# Derivative with respect to a derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative, euler-lagrange-equation

Let $q=q(t)\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $V=V(x)\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$. My book uses the following fact over and over again
$$\frac{\partial V(q)}{\partial \dot{q}}=0.$$
Why is this true?

Comment: Can you provide more context? What is the domain of $V(x)$?

Comment: The domain of $V(x)$ is $\mathbb{R}$. Take $V(x)=x$ if you want.
I'm reading some calculations related to the Euler-Lagrange equation and my book uses this fact, as I've said.
(It's the first time I encounter a derivative with respect to a function)

Answer (score 3):

Don't think of $\dot{q}$ as a derivative, but as an independent variable. This equation shows up in mechanics where $V(q)$ describes the potential of a field. It states that $V$ represents a field depending on positions $q$ *only* and not velocities $\dot{q}$.

If you had a dissipative field $V(q,\dot{q})$ then $\frac{\partial V}{\partial \dot{q}} \neq 0$.

Example of a conservative field would be gravity or electrostatic potential

$$ V(q) = -\frac{K}{q} $$

Comment: Concise and accurate.  +1